# Can I view the source of precompiled views in Razor for ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to see the output of the class that is generated from [Razor](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor) using [Razor Tooling](https://github.com/aspnet/RazorTooling) in ASP.NET Core MVC 1.1.0.

There seems to be no intermediate file stage and no option to output the class as plain text. The file that is generated is a DLL that is stored in a directory you specify, so the class is already in a compiled form.  I have tried using Telerik's [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) but it says that "JustDecompile supports only valid CLR assemblies." and it won't inspect the output.

Is it possible to see the source of the generated class?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a way to view that source, I kinda think I saw @DamianEdwards talk about that/Do quick demo on one of the .Net Core community Standups.  But alas I don't remember which one and it was not the main topic of that standup.  If no one else answers, you might try asking him in a tweet.